# Haskell: receiving a list and iterate several times

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to draw something in the screen.

My function receiving a list of int by parameter (for instance [0,0,0,5,5,5,3,3,3,2,4,4,0] ) and I've to iterate several times from the largest number ([0,0,0,5,5,5,3,3,3,2,4,4,0]) --> 5) until 0

In each iteration I've to examine the entire list, and generate a String (concatenating " ", "-" and "\n"). Writing the result is suppose to be something like this:

```
   ***
   ***    **
   ****** **
   *********
   *********
-------------
```

My function is:

```
generateSTR (x:xs) = daux (x:xs) (maximum (x:xs)) (x:xs) ""
  where daux (h:hs) mh (y:ys) strdib
           |  mh /= 0 && length(h:hs) == 0       = daux (y:ys) (mh-1) (y:ys) "\n" ++ strdib
           | mh > h && mh > 0 && (h:hs) /= []    = daux hs mh (y:ys) "" ++ strdib
           | mh <= h && mh > 0 && (h:hs) /= []   = daux hs mh (y:ys) "*" ++ strdib
           | mh == 0 && length(h:hs) > 0         = daux hs mh hs "-" ++ strdib
        daux [] 0 [] strdib = strdib
        daux [] _ _ strdib = strdib
```

The problem is that I'm only getting the first line in the draw (b is a blank "").

```
bbb***bbbbbbb
```

This first line is OK, but I don't know why my program stops. For sure I'm doing something wrong when I'm trying to restore de original list (the third parameter in the function).

The third parameter is suppose to "save" the original list and after consume the entire list, concatenate a "\n" and restore the original list, continue with the next iteration until 0.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: its not clear (at least for me) how do you process the list, I mean what is the relation about the list, the max num and the output?

Comment: Yes, I'm also unclear about what you are intending. Can you give a few examples of the input and desired output?

Comment: Note that `length (h:hs) == 0` is never true, and `(h:hs) /= []` is always true. Same for `length (h:hs) > 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your code gets so hairy that you can't debug it, it's good to take a step back and try a new approach to the problem. Preferably one building off smaller, testable components.

In this case, you're trying to generate a vertical bar chart given a list of heights. As you've discovered, doing so is *hard*. But we can easily generate a horizontal bar, right? That's just `n` repetitions of the `*` character.

```
bar :: Int -> String
bar n = replicate n '*'

-- bar 5 = "*****"
```

The next tricky bit is rotating it so that it's vertical. What would that look like as a Haskell value? Instead of a simple `String`, we'd have a list of `String`s that each represent a row. So if we have `[replicate n '*']` as a single row of length n, what we want is `replicate n ['*']`, or n rows of length 1. We can use that definition directly, but it turns out that this operation is just transposing a matrix, provided by the function `Data.List.transpose`.

```
verticalBar :: Int -> [String]
verticalBar n = transpose [bar n]

-- verticalBar 5 = ["*","*","*","*","*"]
```

This should point us at how to turn a list of horizontal bars into a vertical graph.

```
transpose . map bar
```

But this isn't quite right, as we lose some elements and the graph appears to be upside down! We need to pad out each row so that our horizontally laid out graph isn't ragged before we transpose it.

```
graph :: [Int] -> String
graph heights = unlines . transpose . map draw $ heights
  where
    maxHeight = maximum heights
    draw height = replicate (maxHeight - height) ' ' ++ replicate height '*' ++ "-"
```

And now we have our graph!

```
λ putStrLn $ graph [0,0,0,5,5,5,3,3,3,2,4,4,0]
   ***
   ***    **
   ****** **
   *********
   *********
-------------
```

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you!